# PowerShell AddScript API doesn't accept pipeline input

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm writing a simple C# PowerShell host, and want users to be able to add a small expression for pipeline clean up (sorting, filtering, etc).

The problem is that PowerShell doesn't seem to treat the script as accepting input.  I've tried the [example from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182436%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and it doesn't work:

```
PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("get-process").
                                            AddScript("foreach { $_.Name }")
```

Which throws a `System.Management.Automation.ParseException` because it's treating `foreach` as the loop operator rather than the command alias.

So I replaced that with an explicit cmdlet:

```
PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("get-process").
                                            AddScript("ForEach-Object { $_.Name }")
```

Which returns returns a collection containing only `null`, presumably because no input is getting to the script at the end.

So what's the deal?  How do I get a script expression in a pipeline to evaluate the same way it would on the commandline?  I don't want my users to have to worry about setting up cmdlet binding explicitly.

Comment: `PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("Get-Process").AddCommand("Invoke-Command").AddArgument(ScriptBlock.Create("&foreach { $_.Name }"))`

Comment: That does seem to work as expected!  Can you explain what the '&' character does?

Comment: `&` is invoke operator. In this particular case it says: next thing is command, not keyword.